# Jquery: cyrillic signs turn into question marks upon submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, utf-8

I use jquery and ajax to submit UTF-8 text, to ensure everything is utf-8, I've put the following in web.config:

```
<globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="en"
    />
```

Jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/EditProductTranslations/")",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
    success: function (result) {
        //$('#@resultDiv').html(result);

        var info = $("<span class='successMsg'></span>").hide().html(result);
        info.insertAfter(curSubmit).fadeIn(300).delay(2700).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

I've also verified it's UTF-8 data by using notepad++ to convert it to UTF-8 (though when it was pasted it said it was UTF-8 already and the data displays perfectly on a UTF-8 site). But I just get ???????? instead of cyrillic signs when I save the form.

The Layout file of the project also has UTF-8 declaring meta-tags, I've done all the usual stuff. Tried to run the submit on firefox with firebug running and it seems everything is submitted correctly? Do I need to declare UTF-8 inside the controller or what?

Comment: Are you just echoing the result back? Or does it go to database first? At every input/output point there is an opportunity for an encoding screwup.

Comment: The jquery submits it straight a controller that saves it to the database (a MySQL database with utf-8 encoding). I am using entity framework for the DB work.

Comment: Is the connection encoding UTF-8 too? That is set in code, not in database.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that was it, adding ;CharSet=utf8 to the connection string fixed it :) Could you make that suggestion a real answer so I can approve it and mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `;CharSet=utf8` to the connection string